# Clang-Format doesn't indent template functions in header files

Tags: clang-format

I'm having this problem with clang-format not properly indenting my header files. For example, I have a template function in a class and I would expect it to be formatted like so:

```cpp
template <class T>
class Thing {
public:
    T function() {
        stuff();
        return T;
    }
}
```

I feel like this indentation would happen automatically, however, it doesn't. When I run Clang-format, my function code is indented like this:

```cpp
template <class T>
class Thing {
public:
    T function() {
    stuff();
    return T;
    }
}
```

How do I get the code in my header files to be formatted like the top one, and not the bottom one?

Below is my .clang-format file:

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Inline
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: true
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass: false
  AfterControlStatement: false
  AfterEnum: false
  AfterFunction: false
  AfterNamespace: false
  AfterStruct: false
  AfterUnion: false
  AfterExternBlock: false
  BeforeCatch: false
  BeforeElse: false
  IndentBraces: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon
ColumnLimit: 80
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: true
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 2
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
IndentCaseLabels: false
IndentWidth: 4
Language: Cpp
NamespaceIndentation: All
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 0
PenaltyBreakComment: 2000
PenaltyBreakString: 3000
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 1000
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 100000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 10000
PointerAlignment: Left
SortIncludes: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesInAngles: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
Standard: Cpp11
UseTab: ForIndentation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened your config file in [this online clang format generator](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/) and looked for settings which would be applicable for your example code.

How does this look ?

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
AccessModifierOffset: '-2'
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Inline
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon
ColumnLimit: '80'
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: '4'
ContinuationIndentWidth: '2'
IndentWidth: '2'
Language: Cpp
NamespaceIndentation: All
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: '0'
PenaltyBreakComment: '2000'
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: '1000'
PenaltyBreakString: '3000'
PenaltyExcessCharacter: '100000'
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: '10000'
PointerAlignment: Left
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
Standard: Cpp11
UseTab: Never
```

I think maybe the `UseTab: Never` or `AccessModifierOffset: '-2'` are the relevant settings. There seems to alos be a relation between `IndentWidth:` and `AccessModifierOffset` when the later is bigger than the former indentations get messed up.

If these are not the settings you are looking for [zed0](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/) is a easy resource to work with for creating an clang format file one can live with.

Comment: The problem line is UseTab: ForAlignment. However, I still want to use tabs for alignment instead of filling everything with spaces. Is there a solution that doesn't require changing UseTab?

Comment: @mkamerath Side note it is fairly common to use spaces, and your question was formatted with spaces, and you did not mention tab anywhere in your question.